# Spatial Data Issue for Client Code Generation OpenRIA

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, devart, domainservices

I have a Property in Entity Framework 6 Entity Class

```
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(DbGeometryConverter))]
    public global::System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry Geom
    {
        get
        {
            global::System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry value = _Geom;
            OnGetGeom(ref value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Geom != value)
            {
              OnGeomChanging(ref value);
              ReportPropertyChanging("Geom");
              _Geom = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
              ReportPropertyChanged("Geom");
              OnGeomChanged();
          }
        }
    }
```

Resulted my OpenRIA Doamin Service client code generation is giving the issue. and it say this property is an unsupportied Type. 
Why this is Happening? And how to resolve this issue?
Is this a serialization issue? if it is how to resolve it.

Comment: This is what @ColinBlair  Said
http://www.openriaservices.net/MonoX/Pages/SocialNetworking/Discussion/dtopic/Y4SquO4cUEaqiaP1ATo_PA/OpenRiaServices-Silverlight-4-4-0-0-compilation-errors-in-generated-code/

Any work Around for this?